# Updating the airflow database by scheduling a job to Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, rbac

This sounds counter intuitive, but what would be the pros and cons of updating the airflow database by deploying a job to airflow?

I am considering this as an option to set up role based accesses by directly making updates to the database, and because Airflow is a scheduler, it would make sense to do schedule this process on Airflow.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kal, could you please include the code you are trying to get working, double-check the 'how to ask a question' guide for further information.

Answer (score 0):

We actually do this to purge down the `logs` table periodically along with some other general Airflow housekeeping. The downsides aren't too bad assuming you tested your code elsewhere first and you're not running the process on an extremely small schedule.

I would recommend that you read the `airflow.models` module and classes, and how they're used, and that you leverage them as examples for your process; it'll help to make sure you're doing things correctly and save you from needless duplication.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I ended up going a different way. I scheduled changes on the server and interacted with the UI using the appbuilder object instead.